# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: globalThis

Tags: angular, firebase

I have a angular 9 based website which is hosted in firebase.
I have an issue which happens only on some devices like iphone 6/7/8. Not all of them but really often.

**Error text**:
main-es5.d57a465….js:1 ReferenceError: Can't find variable: globalThis(anonymous function) @ main-es5.d57a465….js:1spgP @ main-es5.d57a465….js:1a @ runtime-es5.7388edc….js:1zUnb @ main-es5.d57a465….js:1a @ runtime-es5.7388edc….js:1(anonymous function) @ main-es5.d57a465….js:1a @ runtime-es5.7388edc….js:1t @ runtime-es5.7388edc….js:1r @ runtime-es5.7388edc….js:1global code @ main-es5.d57a465….js:1

**Another error:**
main-es2015.d57a465….js:1 ReferenceError: Can't find variable: globalThis(anonymous function) @ main-es2015.d57a465….js:1spgP @ main-es2015.d57a465….js:1a @ runtime-es2015.7388edc….js:1zUnb @ main-es2015.d57a465….js:1a @ runtime-es2015.7388edc….js:1(anonymous function) @ main-es2015.d57a465….js:1a @ runtime-es2015.7388edc….js:1t @ runtime-es2015.7388edc….js:1module code @ main-es2015.d57a465….js:1evaluate @ [native code]:1moduleEvaluation @ [native code]:1

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

iOS Safari support for `globalThis` is version 12.2 or later.

For earlier versions, you will need a [polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/globalthis). check if `globalThis` is not defined then include the polyfill.

And if your app is always running in a browser just replace globalThis with window

Answer (score 1):

Best way to solve this problem in `Angular <11` is to add in index.html

```
<script src="//unpkg.com/@ungap/global-this"></script>
```

Thanks for this solution https://github.com/ungap/global-this